# set up boundary for a triple integral in spherical form

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was asked to do this tripe integral in spherical form $$\iiint  y  dxdydz $$
with boundary $$-1<x<0, -\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{6(x^2+y^2)}<z<\sqrt{7-(x^2+y^2)}$$
I know how to transform $ x,y,z$ into spherical coordinate separately and $x^2+y^2={ρ^2sin{\phi}}^2$but how can I set up the boundary  for ρ and Φ? I was only able to figure out the y boundary is a circle so $0<\theta<2\pi$

Comment: The region is symmetric to y-plane and your integrand is an odd function with respect to $y$ so the integral is zero.

Comment: Btw the projection of the region in z-plane is half circle between $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: appreciate your response, but I still want to figure out the process of this in case the integrand is not an odd function and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the integral is simply zero as the integrand is $y$ (an odd function) and the region is symmetric to y-plane. But if you are asked to convert the bounds into spherical coordinates, please note from the bounds of $z$ that the region is bound between a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 7$ and cone $z = \sqrt{6(x^2+y^2)}$.

At intersection of sphere and cone, $z^2 = 6(x^2+y^2) = 7 - (x^2+y^2)$
$\implies x^2+y^2 = 1$, which is the given bound of $x$ and $y$ but only for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$.

To visualize, the region is half of a spherical cone.

For $\rho$, we are bound by the sphere, $0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt7$.

Bounds of $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$

For $\phi$, we are bound above by the cone,

$ \sqrt{6(x^2+y^2)} = z \implies \sqrt6 \rho \sin\phi = \rho \cos\phi$

$0 \leq \phi \leq \arctan ({\frac{1}{\sqrt6}})$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\arctan ({\frac{1}{\sqrt6}})} \int_{0}^{\sqrt7} \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \rho^3 \sin\theta \sin^2\phi \ d\theta \ d\rho \ d\phi $

And the integral is zero (as integral of $\sin\theta$ between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is zero for the same reason as mentioned earlier).